# Create a new window in Qt which depends on the parent window, but appears outside of the parent window

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt4

I want to implement a log for my application, and I want it to be in another window. But of course it should close when the main window is closed.

The main window is created with class Window which inherits from QWidget.

When I create the second window the same way and pass into the constructor "this" as parent, that does not work, everything that is inside new window appears inside parent window. But when I don't pass anything into the constructor of new window, it does not close when the parent window closed.

Comment: You need to set window flags of the new window correctly to make it separate window even when it has parent. Alternatively, you can make it parentless, and close it in your own code, when the main window closes.

Comment: What about a dialog?

Answer (score 2):

Try to create the second window which inherits from QDialog.

```
#ifndef FORM_H
#define FORM_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class Form;
}

class Form : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Form(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Form();
private slots:

private:
    Ui::Form *ui;
};

#endif // FORM_H
```

And MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "QDebug"
#include "form.h"
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(showNewWindow()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::showNewWindow()
{
    Form *form;
    form = new Form(this);
    form->setModal(false);
    form->show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As @hyde commented, you should set `Qt::Window` for the window flags when you create the window widget, and then you can give it a parent and it will be a "secondary window" and will close when the parent closes.  Inheriting from `QDialog` is fine, but brings along additional baggage that you may not want/need; the simple answer to the question is to use `Qt::Window`.